# Using Poisson structure to determine compatibility of overdetermined system of pdes

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, integrable-systems

Consider the following question

> Consider the Poisson structure
> $$
> \{F, G\}=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\delta F}{\delta u(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\delta G}{\delta u(x)} d x,
> $$
> where $F, G$ are polynomial functionals of $u, u_x, u_{x x}, \ldots$ Assume that $u, u_x, u_{x x}, \ldots$ tend to zero as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$.
> (i) Show that $\{F, G\}=-\{G, F\}$.
> (ii) Write down Hamilton's equations for $u=u(x, t)$ corresponding to the following Hamiltonians:
> $$
> H_0[u]=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{2} u^2 d x, \quad H[u]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{2} u_x{ }^2+u^3+u u_x\right) d x .
> $$
> (iii) Calculate the Poisson bracket $\left\{H_0, H\right\}$, and hence or otherwise deduce that the following overdetermined system of partial differential equations for $u=u\left(x, t_0, t\right)$ is compatible:
> $$
> \begin{gathered}
> u_{t_0}=u_x, \\
> u_t=6 u u_x-u_{x x x} .
> \end{gathered}
> $$
> [You may assume that the Jacobi identity holds for (1).]

I was able to do the first two parts of the question, where note that hamiltons equations with respect tothe hamiltonians turn out to be (2) and (3). I was also able to, by force show that
$$
\{H_0,H\}=0.
$$

However, I am not sure how to proceed. Per the question I assume that I need to use the Jacobi identity
$$\{F,\{G, H\}\}+\{G,\{H, F\}\}+\{H,\{F, G\}\}=0.$$
This suggests we set two of the hamiltonians be the one in the question, but I do not have an idea as to what should be the third.

Moreover, I do not really understand what the question is asking of me. Am I asked to show that
$$
u_t= u_{t_0}?
$$

**Question:** What is being asked of me in the end of (iii) and how does one approach it?